# jQuery val() returns starting value instead of current value, possibly because of Prettyphoto

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

jQuery's `val()` is returning the starting value instead of the current value in my form...

I have it integrated inside a prettyphoto pane on my website, but for the jsFiddle, I didn't bother importing all the css and stuff to make it pop out.

The JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/4DSdq/1/

```
$("#edit-name").live("keyup", function() {
                        alert("id: "+$("#edit-id").val());
                        alert("name: "+$("input[id=edit-name]").val());
});
```

returns 32 and '' respectively, irrespective of what is actually in them at the moment...

Any ideas?

Comment: Your fiddle is not working
http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/wp-content/themes/NMFE/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js

Comment: did you try your fiddle before posting ?

Comment: yes, I tried the fiddle before posting.

Comment: Not sure why you got two down-votes. Thank you for supplying the fiddle.

Comment: Why do you use `$("input[id=edit-name]")` instead of `$("#edit-name")` or just `$(this)`?

Comment: Honestly, I am not all that experienced with JS and Jquery, I was trying every iteration I could figure to see if I could get it working, in case I was just making a mistake. I also tried the others.

Answer (score 0):

The value inside the 'edit-id' input tag is being explicitly stated (I'm assuming by the prettyphoto plugin). The value is set to "32" and does not change on input. I would take a look at how the plugin handles this action and see if you can repair it.

This is your rendered html code for the 'edit-id' element:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="128" name="id" id="edit-id" size="50" value="32" class="form-text required">
```

It remains static because it has an explicitly stated `value` attribute.